# Xcode 5 developer preview crash on launch

Tags: crash, preview, crash-reports, xcode5

This Xcode 5 DP version was downloaded from internet which uploaded by anyone else. Every time i clicked it on launch up, it'll crash at once. Cuz i had installed xcode 4.6 version before, and i'm just registered as a developer, but didn't pay $99 a year for credit card.

I don't make sure this is the problem cause crashed. Any one can help me solve problems? Big appreciate for that!

This is the xcode 5 DP crash log:

```
Process:         Xcode [561]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode5-DP.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         5.0 (3322.38)
Build Info:      IDEApplication-3322038000000000~4
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [147]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2013-06-12 11:28:58.292 +0800
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.3 (12D78)
Report Version:  10

Interval Since Last Report:          525462 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           25
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  446 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   18
Anonymous UUID:                      A9DA8062-D29B-6AC1-2555-14D6D838145A

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 5A11314m
*** error for object 0x7fae2b97b130: pointer being freed was not allocated


Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff81341212 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff844f4b54 pthread_kill + 90
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff84538dce abort + 143
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8450c9b9 free + 392
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff8ac6dfc0 object_dispose + 54
5   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x00000001040d7365 __DVTSetupKVODeallocAssertions_block_invoke_371 + 264
6   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff8ac6e230 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 464
7   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8cbb3d72 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 34
8   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8c475ada -[NSAutoreleasePool drain] + 154
9   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8c47d580 _NSAppleEventManagerGenericHandler + 125
10  com.apple.AE                    0x00007fff8da45078 aeDispatchAppleEvent(AEDesc const*, AEDesc*, unsigned int, unsigned char*) + 307
11  com.apple.AE                    0x00007fff8da44ed9 dispatchEventAndSendReply(AEDesc const*, AEDesc*) + 37
12  com.apple.AE                    0x00007fff8da44d99 aeProcessAppleEvent + 318
13  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff85bae709 AEProcessAppleEvent + 100
14  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff88e29866 _DPSNextEvent + 1456
15  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff88e28e22 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 128
16  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff88e201d3 -[NSApplication run] + 517
17  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff88dc4c06 NSApplicationMain + 869
18  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff881417e1 start + 1

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff813416d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff844f5f4c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff844f5d13 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff844e01d1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff81341d16 kevent + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8b480dea _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 883
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8b4809ee _dispatch_mgr_thread + 54

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff813416d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff844f5f4c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff844f5d13 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff844e01d1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff813416d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff844f5f4c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff844f5d13 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff844e01d1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff813416d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff844f5f4c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff844f5d13 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff844e01d1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 6:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.low-priority
0   com.apple.DiskArbitration       0x00007fff8c034fa6 _DADiskInitialize + 16
1   com.apple.DiskArbitration       0x00007fff8c034d4c __DAInitialize + 16
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff844f4ff0 pthread_once + 87
3   com.apple.DiskArbitration       0x00007fff8c034bc7 DASessionCreate + 21
4   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89071f56 __48-[NSApplication _initializeAutomaticTermination]_block_invoke_01143 + 43
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8b481f01 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8b47e0b6 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8b47f1fa _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 304
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff844f5d0b _pthread_wqthread + 404
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff844e01d1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 7:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8133f686 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8133ec42 mach_msg + 70
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8cbb3233 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 195
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8cbb8916 __CFRunLoopRun + 1078
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8cbb80e2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8c452b66 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 356
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8c4b0cd2 __NSThread__main__ + 1345
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff844f37a2 _pthread_start + 327
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff844e01e1 thread_start + 13

Thread 8:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff81341322 __select + 10
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8cbf7f46 __CFSocketManager + 1302
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff844f37a2 _pthread_start + 327
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff844e01e1 thread_start + 13

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff813416d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff844f5f4c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff844f5d13 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff844e01d1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff813416d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff844f5f4c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff844f5d13 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff844e01d1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8133f686 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8133ec42 mach_msg + 70
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8cbb3233 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 195
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8cbb8916 __CFRunLoopRun + 1078
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8cbb80e2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290
5   com.apple.DTDeviceKitBase       0x000000010d269f0a -[DTDKRemoteDeviceDataListener listenerThreadImplementation] + 164
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8c4b0cd2 __NSThread__main__ + 1345
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff844f37a2 _pthread_start + 327
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff844e01e1 thread_start + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000000000006  rcx: 0x00007fff5bbf5d78  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000c07  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x00007fff5bbf5da0  rsp: 0x00007fff5bbf5d78
   r8: 0x00007fff717de278   r9: 0x0000000000000081  r10: 0x0000000020000000  r11: 0x0000000000000206
  r12: 0x00007fae2989ce00  r13: 0x00000001050c6000  r14: 0x00007fff717df180  r15: 0x0000000000000008
  rip: 0x00007fff81341212  rfl: 0x0000000000000206  cr2: 0x00007fae28832200
Logical CPU: 0

Binary Images:
       0x104009000 -        0x104009ff7  com.apple.dt.Xcode (5.0 - 3322.38) <5CE4EAEB-6D86-3485-8946-05F729BD3DBB> /Applications/Xcode5-DP.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
       0x10400e000 -        0x104429fff  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation (5.0 - 3481.6) <BB2B9FCE-80FA-39D4-9FE9-F4EC12019F2D> /Applications/Xcode5-DP.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/DVTFoundation
       0x104599000 -        0x1048b0fff  com.apple.dt.DVTKit (5.0 - 3502.3) <2D8CB62B-5437-3FD3-9B99-24C55AB7197E> /Applications/Xcode5-DP.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
       0x104a50000 -        0x104e78ff7  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation (5.0 - 3504.7) <8CEB5828-80F5-3C6F-BBEE-F30975A5965B> /Applications/Xcode5-DP.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEFoundation.framework/Versions/A/IDEFoundation
       0x1050c9000 -        0x105841fff  com.apple.dt.IDEKit (5.0 - 3527.7) <27FE8EAE-A006-3556-B57E-E5F3169DDC3F> /Applications/Xcode5-DP.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Versions/A/IDEKit
       0x105caa000 -        0x105d4cfff  com.apple.PackageKit (3.0 - 260) <B9C3BB80-C2A3-3E9E-A9C0-EB58B5F42512> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PackageKit.framework/Versions/A/PackageKit
       0x105dbc000 -        0x105dbcff7  libsysmon.dylib (2) <E029BDA7-E063-3049-95FF-BBA1AF41DFB0> /usr/lib/libsysmon.dylib
       0x105e6d000 -        0x105e7cff7  libSimplifiedChineseConverter.dylib (61) <A2B475FF-667F-3B7B-A6E9-8768347F2BD6> /System/Library/CoreServices/Encodings/libSimplifiedChineseConverter.dylib
       0x1066d7000 -        0x106757fff  com.apple.dt.IBFoundation (1.0 - 1) <B9E81B5F-A0B9-395A-B2B4-5063A07791DC> /Applications/Xcode5-DP.app/Contents/Frameworks/IBFoundation.framework/Versions/A/IBFoundation
       0x1067a6000 -        0x1067d4ff7  com.apple.CoreThemeDefinition (1.0 - 104) <BE976F3F-9085-3E00-AD9E-FC1A5458FB49> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreThemeDefinition.framework/Versions/A/CoreThemeDefinition
       0x1067f6000 -        0x10682bff7  com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerFoundation (5.0 - 3490.2) <8AFF3717-11FF-3B86-A78B-8E79822DC9A1> /Applications/Xcode5-DP.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerFoundation.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DebuggerFoundation
       0x106862000 -        0x107117ff7 +libclang.dylib (500.1.58) <054AB067-A22B-396F-9C48-EEC76DF12A2B> /Applications/Xcode5-DP.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/libclang.dylib
       0x107192000 -        0x1071e9fff  com.apple.CSServiceClient (1.0 - 1) <BD9C72AA-FF23-324C-90ED-A4243FAD34BE> /Applications/Xcode5-DP.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/CSServiceClient.framework/Versions/A/CSServiceClient
       0x10721a000 -        0x10723cfff  com.apple.DADocSetManagement (5.0 - 3338.1) <BF03D04F-3BD0-3750-B8AF-9544828510C5> /Applications/Xcode5-DP.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DADocSetManagement.framework/Versions/A/DADocSetManagement
       0x107258000 -        0x10725aff7  com.apple.dt.DVTDeveloperModeHelper (1.0 - 1) <A3DBC1CB-A24E-3908-92A0-13EC2E56BD99> /Applications/Xcode5-DP.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTDeveloperModeHelper.framework/Versions/A/DVTDeveloperModeHelper
```

Comment: This sounds like something you need to report to http://bugreport.apple.com or to ask on their developer forums. Betas are going to crash, that's what they do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be you have Xcode plugins installed.
Try to remove them.

```
rm ~/Library/Application\ Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/*
```

Comment: my xcode still crashing after remove this